# Can upper body exercise strain the legs unnecessarily in long-term?

Tags: upper-body-workout

Can upper body exercise strain the legs unnecessarily in long-term?

I've lifted weights in the past, but after thinking that my legs are the most important part of my body, then I've speculated that:

- Building mass in the upper body puts more strain on the legs.
- If this mass is not used for anything, then it's not useful for anything.

But then I've been cautious about:

- Do too low levels of activity on the upper body and e.g. arms lead to some sort of dysfunction? For example, that after 10 years of not training the upper body my arm and even finger coordination would have worsened considerably.

Certainly one will lose muscle mass from the upper body, but I am yet to understand whether having little muscle is bad, if one doesn't need big muscles for anything.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't true that upper body muscle is just extra mass that "is not used for anything."  Your upper body actually contributes to your running ability  as discussed in [this article](https://www.runnersworld.com/news/a35700370/stronger-upper-body-improves-running-efficiency-study/).  (Source:  Runner's World)

Keeping up with your upper body workouts is also beneficial for your [overall health](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/reasons-to-exercise-upper-body_n_57309a6de4b0bc9cb04753dc).  (Source:  Huffington Post)

Furthermore, I would disagree that "Building mass in the upper body puts more strain on the legs."  Your body is not like a machine that simply accumulates wear and tear as it's used.[1]  Instead, it adapts to increased training volume (as long as you're not *over*training and are also getting good sleep and nutrition).  The extra weight from well-developed upper body muscles will indeed place extra load on your legs, but this should[2] actually help your legs become stronger.  They will adapt to the extra training volume (in this case from your higher overall mass) just as they would if you added more weight on leg-specific exercises like the squat or leg press.

---

[1] In fact, it seems to be the opposite: "[Research shows that many of the changes attributed to aging are actually caused in large part by disuse.](https://www.health.harvard.edu/staying-healthy/exercise-and-aging-can-you-walk-away-from-father-time)" And, "[the presence of a relatively large quantity of skeletal muscle mass may result in the secretion of high levels of favorable myokines, resulting in beneficial effects on glucose uptake and lipid metabolism.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7090295/#:~:text=Therefore%2C%20the%20presence%20of%20a,glucose%20uptake%20and%20lipid%20metabolism.)"  Or, to rephrase that without the medical jargon, *having more muscle mass might also benefit your metabolism*.  (Sources: Harvard Health Publishing and the National Library of Medicine)

[2] Assuming, of course, that you don't have an injury or other medical issue preventing you from doing normal training - in that case, you should discuss your exercise plan with a doctor or physical therapist!

Comment: I've had a different belief w.r.t. the wearing and tearing. I thought joints do not recover much, but are like brake plates that wear until they need to be replaced. Or maybe there's recovery, but only if the rate of wear does not surpass the recovery rate.

Comment: This sounds like a follow-up question.  For that I would refer you to this Harvard Health Publishing article https://www.health.harvard.edu/newsletter_article/exercise-and-your-joints  which seems like a perfect fit for your second question.  It cites multiple studies on the effects of exercise on the knees, showing it to be either neutral or beneficial (so, not damaging to the joints).

Comment: Also, this source discusses the benefits of both upper and lower body exercises on the joints:  https://www.campbellclinic.com/the-benefits-of-exercise-on-your-joints/

Comment: And here, for positive effects of exercise in arthritis patients: https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/arthritis/in-depth/arthritis/art-20047971 Some relevant quotes: "Exercises for arthritis might include exercises that put joints through their full range of motion and strengthening exercises." and "Weight training should be done every other day for at least two days a week. It should include all the major muscles in the body."

Comment: "In general, movement is essential for maintaining joint health.  Use of joints naturally increases flexibility and strength, but motion also lubricates joints and reduces swelling.  Not only will exercise help maintain joint health in the long term, but it will also help reduce joint pain symptoms almost immediately due to production of natural pain killers called endorphins." - from https://coloradopaincare.com/how-your-joints-benefit-from-exercise/